# Split up a csv file / pandas dataframe into many files based on grouping in another column

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, csv

I have the following dataset in a csv file called list.csv which is 2 columns and 68 rows,

```
name   group
295h1  groupA
20jca  groupA
....
2919d  groupG
....
2xx9a  groupM
```

Each group is 3-5 names long.

I want to split up the names into their groups and save the files into csv files like this.

`group-1.csv`

```
295h1
20jca
..
```

`group-13.csv`

```
...
2xx9a
```

So far I have the following code,

```
import pandas as pd

counter = 1
tlist = []
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    previousGroup = None
    if row['group'] == previousGroup:
        tlist.append(row['name'])
        previousGroup = row['group']
    else:
        with open(f'group-{counter}'), 'w',) as myfile:
             wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
             wr.writerow(tlist)
        counter += 1
        tlist = []
```

But it creates 68 empty files which is the length of the csv file.

How can I split up this file properly based on my requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need instead names of groups `groupA` use numbers starting by `1` use:

```
for i, (_, group) in enumerate(df.groupby('group'), 1):
    group['name'].to_csv(f'group-{i}.csv', index=False)
```

EDIT: For first value in file is one idea create `MultiIndex` like:

```
for i, (n, group) in enumerate(df.groupby('group'), 1):
    g = group[['name']]
    g.columns = [[n], g.columns]
    #print (g)
    g.to_csv(f'group-{i}.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: I only want to save the 'name' column

Comment: no I mean, it has to be grouped by the 'group' column but the 'name' column has to be saved

Comment: @anarchy - answer was edited, need `df['name'].to_csv`

Comment: when I use enumerate though it only saves 1 file

Comment: @anarchy - sorry, my typo, is necessary grouping by `group`

Comment: I figured it out, its because u used the same variable, don't use df as the temp variable it messed up the code

Comment: @anarchy - Agree, you are right. Better is use `group`. thank you for patience.

Comment: can I ask you one more thing @jezrael do u know if there is a way to append the group name to the first line of the csv file? like as a header or something

Answer (score 0):

You should use the pandas groupby and pd.to_csv()

```
grouped = df.groupby('group')
for num, g in grouped:
    name = 'group' + '.csv'
    g.to_csv(name)
```

Comment: it saves all columns, I only want then 'name' column, how do I do that?